# Using a singleton to get a log4j Logger instance in order to isolate the logger name

Tags: java, servlets, logging, log4j, singleton

I'm using My WebMethods Server which is, among other things, a servlet container. MWS default logging implementation is log4j, so I'm allowed to use it without including any jar in my  project.
Since MWS Root Logger is cross to all the contained applications and the server instance itself, I should not use it. Instead, my approach is to create a new Logger per application. I set the Logger name in a properties file, and intend to read it from the servlet's `init()` method. 
Because of that `logger-name` parameter, I want to decouple the obtaining of the Logger from the page bean code. I've been thinking in creating a Singleton that saves the logger name and gets the Logger instance.

To sum up, I've been thinking in doing something like this:

```
package com.webmethods.caf.log;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CAFLogger {

    private static String appLoggerName;
    private static Logger logger;

    private CAFLogger() {

    }

    public static void setLoggerName(String loggerName) {
        if (appLoggerName == null) {
            appLoggerName = loggerName;
        }
    }

    public static Logger getLoggerInstance() {
        if (logger == null) {
            logger = LogManager.getLogger(appLoggerName);
        }
        return logger;
    }
}
```

And then call `setLoggerName()` from my `init()` method and `getLoggerInstance()` from the page beans.
Is it a very bad idea?

I've been reading other posts regarding the singleton topic, like the following:

[Benefits of Log4j singleton wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846293/benefits-of-log4j-singleton-wrapper)

[Log4J: Strategies for creating Logger instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770076/log4j-strategies-for-creating-logger-instances)

but them all suggest to use the class name to get the Logger object, while I need to use the logger name.

PS. Please excuse my english. I'll be glad to correct any mispelling or grammar mistake based on your comments, as well as add any lacking information.

Answer (score 0):

You can define categories based on package name in `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` in that case you don't need to get the logger by it's name. Just get the logger by class name and based on category it will be logged in appropriate appender.

for e.g.:

```
<category name="com.x.y.z.server">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="SERVER_FILE_LOG" />
</category>

<category name="com.x.y.z.client">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="CLIENT_FILE_LOG" />
</category>
```

Comment: Something I forgot to say is that most classes share the same package structure across all the applications, i.e. begin with `com.webmethods.caf` despite the application they belong to, and there is one package per screen, like `com.webmethods.caf.screen1`. It would be toilsome to define categories by class name. That's why I use the logger name instead of the class to get the Logger object.