# Duplicate log4j lines in console

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

Although similar questions were asked, I couldn't find a solution. I guess because the configuration varies.

I am using a 3rd party jar, but I had the same problem also when using log4j directly.

I am working on Eclipse Mars.1

My log4j.properties is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

 <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
</root>

<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" additivity="false">
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%X{ThreadId}] %X{MethodName} - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" additivity="false">
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
  <param name="append" value="true" />
  <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
  <param name="File" value="c:\Users\administrator\Eclipse workspaces\mylog-${current.date}.log"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%X{ThreadId}] %X{MethodName} - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

</log4j:configuration>
```

And here is an example of what I see in the eclipse console:

```
2015-11-16 17:13:33 DEBUG []  - ConferenceId = 4618311
13082 [main] DEBUG com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton  - ConferenceId = 4618311
13082 [main] DEBUG com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton  - ConferenceId = 4618311
13082 [main] DEBUG com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton  - ConferenceId = 4618311
2015-11-16 17:13:33 INFO  []  - SLEEP_BETWEEN_CREATE_TO_TERMINATE_SEC waiting 2000 ms...
13083 [main] INFO com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton  - SLEEP_BETWEEN_CREATE_TO_TERMINATE_SEC waiting 2000 ms...
13083 [main] INFO com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton  - SLEEP_BETWEEN_CREATE_TO_TERMINATE_SEC waiting 2000 ms...
13083 [main] INFO com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton  - SLEEP_BETWEEN_CREATE_TO_TERMINATE_SEC waiting 2000 ms...
```

And each iteration of code one more duplication is added. If I have now 3 duplications of "SLEEP_BETWEEN_CREATE_TO_TERMINATE_SEC waiting", next loop I will have 4 of them...

Can you advise please?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the section of code where you insert these logging statements.

Comment: I've seen that before when appenders were added over and over again

Comment: Does your code log the debug/info message multiple times - like in a for loop there is something like for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i) { log.info(message); }

Comment: @KLibby I use a 3rd party wrapper, so I don;t think it will help to post the statements.

Comment: @TR1 It is an infinite while loop.

Comment: The duplications are only in the console and not in the file!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'd expect is in your custom Log4j wrapper: `com.log.Log4jWrapperSingleton`

And you should get rid of it. It is very likely serving new instance of it self every time it is called effectivelly adding new logger to the ConsoleAppender (we can only guess until we see the source)

You can find reasoning here: [Benefits of Log4j singleton wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846293/benefits-of-log4j-singleton-wrapper)